# TYPO3: how to show the field in BE only for its owner?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-tca

TCA offers the possibility for conditional displaying fields using [`displayCond`](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html#displaycond). for an instance `HIDE_FOR_NON_ADMINS` allows to display field only for admin, but is there a way to display given field only for its creator, determined by `cruser_id` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box. You can hook into TCEMAIN (DataHandler) or TCEFORM (FormEngine) to archive this.

You can however use access rights and set the rights to show the page (storage folder) only the the given backend user. Check out the access module.

Comment: Brilliant hint with TCEFORM hooks! FYI: I used `getMainFields_preProcess` so at some condition I can just modify column's TCA per row i.e. to set its config to `passthrough`, thx!

Comment: BTW I didn't want to use access rights as I would need to create separate _sysfolder_ for each user, the main goal was to avoid edit possibility for only some fields for non-owners. Hook gives me all I need